# How do I correctly assign and print structure pointers in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, malloc

I have the following two structures.

```
struct string_counter {
  char *string;
  int count;
};


struct container{
  struct string_counter *counters;
  int size;
};
```

And the following functions.

```
void add_string(struct *container, char *string){
    struct string_counter *counter_ptr;
    counter_ptr = new_count(string);

    container->size++;
    container->counters = realloc(container->counters, sizeof(struct string_counter)*container->size);
    container->counters[container->size-1] = *counter_ptr;
    print_string_counter(&container->counters[container->size-1]);
}

struct counter *new_count(char *string){
    struct string_counter *counter_ptr;

    counter_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct string_counter));
    counter_ptr->string = string;
    counter_ptr->count = 1;

    return counter_ptr;
}
```

In my main function I am looping over several times calling`add_string(container_ptr, string)` with the same container pointer and a different string each time, attempting to add the new string to the end of the `string_counter *counters`. Later on in my code when I try printing the contents of the counters using the following two functions:

```
void print_container(struct container *container_ptr){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < container_ptr->size; i++){
         print_string_counter(&container_ptr->counters[i]);
    }
}

void print_string_counter(struct string_counter *counter_ptr){
    printf("%s : %d\n", counter_ptr->string, counter_ptr->count);
}
```

I get extremely incorrect results such as my output below. But earlier when I printed with :

```
print_string_counter(&container->counters[container->size-1])
```

just below :

```
container->counters[container->size-1] = *counter_ptr;
```

in my `add_string()` function, I got the correct results.

[image: My output from <code>print_container</code>]

Initially my container values are

```
struct_counter = NULL;
int size = 0;
```

Why is my output using the loop later on different from originally when I printed it?

Comment: Try `counter_ptr->string = string;` --> `counter_ptr->string = strdup(string);`

Comment: Those are some cool characters you got there...

Comment: changing `counter_ptr->string = string;` to `counter_ptr->string = strdup(string);` gives me a Segmentation fault. I also tried changing it to `strcpy(counter_ptr->string, string);` which also gave me a Segmentation fault.

Comment: I think you mixed up the return of struct counter versus struct string_container in new_struct, along with the sizeof name. Can you turn on more compiler warnings to catch these problems? I think that was the most important one.

Comment: My apologies,  the code I posted is not the exact code I am running, I rewrote it on my desktop from my laptop, I fixed the `sizeof()` problem, but the output still remains. However I noticed that the last two outputs, 7 and 8, always have the same output, while the other 7 seem to change every time.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is likely that your `string_counter` struct does nat actually store the strings -- it just stores pointers, which will be point at whatever you pass in.  In `new_count`, if that string you pass in is in a temporary buffer (say the buffer you use to read input in `main`), then when that buffer goes away, the pointer in the `string_counter` will be left dangling and when you later go to print, you'll get whatever garbage happens to be in memory where your original buffer was.

Related (but indpendent) your `container` struct maintains an array of `string_counter` objects, not pointers, so when you call `add_string`, it extends the array AND calls `new_count` to allocate a new `string_counter`.  It then copies that newly allocated object and leaks it.

So what you likely need is in `new_counter` to copy the string as well.  You can also fix the second problem by having `new_count` return an object rather than a pointer:

```
struct counter new_count(char *string){
    struct string_counter counter;

    counter.string = strdup(string);
    counter.count = 1;

    return counter;
}
```